# Why the fps of a video video file is not same?

Tags: video, frame-rate

I have a wmv video file that concatenate two wmv files using ffmpeg.

The fps in file property, it shows 30 frames/second.
And from ffprobe or media info, it shows 25 frames/second.
Why it isn't same?
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What technology do you use? How do you display the video? Is this a programming question at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the fps in file property just copied information from the original file, but editing or changing video files can easily cause a drop in quality or fps. This just means it's slightly inaccurate.

It's also likely that they just use different methods to measure fps and it doesn't always return the same results. That would just be the way of things, nothing you can really do about that.

To prevent this, you'll need to play with the settings of ffmpeg and increase your quality and bitrate settings, which will cause the file to be larger in size.

This might also help with more information: http://www.mediacollege.com/video/editing/faq/quality.html

Comment: Thanks your reply. So how can I fix this problem?